# how to find the checked radio button in an aspx page

Tags: c#

I have a list of radio button, not radiobuttonlist, I need to find out which one is checked. The container is a div. But I also have other controls in this div. How to find the checked radio button?
My code is as follows:

```
  foreach (RadioButton rb in divContainer.Controls)
        {
            ....

        }
```

It comes out with an error whhich says "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.ResourceBasedLiteralControl' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.RadioButton'."

This is a .net web application, I use c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the loop to:

```
foreach (RadioButton rb in divContainer.Controls.OfType<WebControls.RadioButton>())
{
   ....
```

This will loop only controls of the desired type. If you cannot use Linq, you could try to use "is" to know if the control is a RadioButton and if it's the case use it otherwise continue to the next one.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an old school (non LINQ) way...

```
foreach (Control ctrl in divContainer.Controls)
{
  bool isRadioButton = ctrl is RadioButton;
  if (!isRadioButton)
    continue;

  RadioButton rb = ctrl as RadioButton;
 ....
}
```